# PDF file isn't downloading

Tags: php, pdf, download, fpdf

I want to download a pdf file with result, I have already generate the pdf using fpdf [$pdf->Output($output_file, 'F');], the pdf file generated is saved in server.

I want user to be able to download the pdf file generated from fpdf anyway. I even tried using other output (http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) but none of them work except for "F".     $pdf->Output($output_file, 'F');(generate pdf successful using this)

I also tried to add a form which will download the existed generated file from server to browser but nothing is working . My code is as below:

```
<form method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download Most Recent PDF">
    <h3>Please check the content of PDF.</h3>
</form>
```

```
    $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "../pdf/Result.pdf";
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

}

I want to generate result(which i successfully did) and let user download the result in pdf version.(where i am stuck).

Comment: When i click on "Download Most Recent PDF" the browser open something like this,..................%PDF-1.4 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�*T0P�R0T(�Y@��� z��F�@���g �z���& ɹ �!> .� �\�iK endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> /Resources 6 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 99 >> stream x-�; �0{O1v�h�I�x�Z 1��l�;0�����XE�:\c9f�!iBB�I��Te���p�|e=a����̿d�1hd��Kdc��n��g endstream endobj 6 0 obj <> /Font <> >> endobj 8 0 obj <> endobj 10 0 obj <> stream x]��n� D�|��C�-B�RE�MT��am!����/7�z�3�`X~n�[

Comment: why don't you just give the file path in $file ? I think your file path is not ok

Comment: "C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-content\plugins\Etc\pdf\pdf\result.pdf"      this is path ...my result pdf is result.pdf

Comment: $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "../pdf/Result.pdf";      for that path ..i can put like this or no?

Comment: why you use plugin_dir_path() ?

Comment: to Get the directory of the current file

Comment: are you using raw php ? or any framework ?

Comment: php............,in wordpress

Comment: I solved it...)

Answer (score 0):

First check your file path is correct or not.debug with that after that if your file is not download than try below code ,

```
    header('Pragma: public');

    header('Expires: 0');

    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

    header('Cache-Control: private', false); 

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($filename) . '";');

    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

   echo file_get_contents($filename);

    exit;
```

Comment: I even tried this, but when i submit form, the page refreshes but file is not downloading

Comment: "C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-content\plugins\Etc\pdf\pdf\result.pdf"

Comment: the result.pdf is the pdf that needs to be download...when i put  plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "../pdf/Result.pdf" or "C:/xampp/htdocs/xx/wp-content/plugins/Etc/pdf/pdf/result.pdf"    either way no difference ...its not downloading

Comment: first print your path with echo $file;  and in if (file_exists($file)) { echo "path exist"; die;}

Comment: ok i understand which file you want to download.Did you check  the path of $file ? is it same as this "C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-content\plugins\Etc\pdf\pdf\result.pdf" path?

Comment: ya...it says path exists

Comment: ohk, so now put pdf generation code there and tell me the file is download or getting some error!!!

Comment: pdf is already generated and is saved in "C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\wp-content\plugins\Etc\pdf\pdf\result.pdf"      so i shoukd be able to download by the code above no? the one i posted in question? there is no progress.......whenever i click to download...it shows werird  contents like i posted up ..and pdf doesnt download

Comment: try this file_get_contents($filename); instead of read file hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry i'm troubling you by asking to many questions but i'm trying to figure out your problem..did you open your generated pdf file on server??Sometimes that happens with me that my pdf file didn't generate properly so i was getting binary data.

Comment: oh ya...The generated pdf looks fine and is exactly how i want, its just i am unable to download it to browser....I want the user to be able to download the result pdf